# How to get rid of the Spring boot missing test configuration message

Tags: spring-boot, junit5

Sup Guys

When running my Spring Boot Tests, i get a load of info that i am missing a testconfiguration.
But thats on purpose. I want to get rid of this message.

```
2024-01-12T22:13:31.359+01:00  INFO 22867 --- [           main] t.c.s.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils : Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [net.internalerror.rest.request.task.ReadDueTaskRequestTest]: ReadDueTaskRequestTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
2024-01-12T22:13:31.363+01:00  INFO 22867 --- [           main] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : Found @SpringBootConfiguration net.internalerror.TasksServer for test class net.internalerror.rest.request.task.ReadDueTaskRequestTest
```

I have tried Configuring Logback and setting Loglevel for the classes to warn, but both things did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the logging level to `warn` for test context:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.test.context: warn
```

Or specify your testing configuration explicitly:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { YourTestConfig.class })
```

Comment: setting log level to warn does not work. Also i do not want to create a test configuration